# How oracle statement works?

Tags: oracle

```
   create table samp
   (
   empno number(2),
   ename varchar2(30),
   sal number(7,2),
   dob date
   )
SQL> /

SQL> insert into samp values(1,'MASTAN',24000,'24-JUL-1987');

1 row created.
```

here i did not commit data so it is in redo log buffer,but when retrieving , how the below Query giving data? How internally works ?kindly suggest me

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM SAMP;

     EMPNO ENAME                                 SAL DOB                              
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ---------
         1 MASTAN                              24000 24-JUL-87
```

Comment: I think the best thing you could do is read the Oracle Concepts Guide for 11g or 12c, which goes into a lot of details on how the database works. It's a big read, but doing so will answer this question and many others that you didn't even know you had yet.

Comment: I think you're talking about [undo](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/undo.htm#i1006145) rather than redo here, but not really relevant anyway as you're querying in the same session. If you were asking about another session *not* seeing that row, undo would be relevant for read consistency, as the documentation explains.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you did not commit or rollback so you are seeing the correct result from your select statement because it happens in single transaction. Try rollback and check the results. Another good way to understand transactions is to try opening two separate sqlplus shell and trying insert statements in one and select statements in the other shell.